# Is this Function differentiable and continuous at x=0?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Is $f(x)$ continuous and differentiable at $x = 0$ ?

$$f(x) = x(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x+1})$$

Comment: You must also take into account the domain of the function, for this particular case the function is not defined for _x_ < 0

Comment: Just differentiate and take the limit as $x \to 0^+$. Of course the left derivative is meaningless here.

Comment: It means that lim x -> 0-  will not exist and hence it should neither be continuos not differentiable. But according to the answer given in the textbook it is continuos and differentiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First $f$ is defined only for $x \ge 0$.

Then, you have $$f(x) = x(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x+1})=x(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x+1})\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1}} = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1}}$$
which is continuous at $x=0$ with $f(0)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 0$. Moreover $$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1}}$$ has a right hand side limit as $x$ goes to $0$ equal to $-1$. So $f^\prime(0)=-1$.

Comment: But if we try to prove continuity at x=0 , then $x \to 0^ should be equal to the left hand limit which is not possible in this case

Comment: @user250085 In fact for a function defined only on one side at a point, continuity means that the limit on only one side is equal to the value of the function. As an example, take the function $g$ equal to $0$ on the interval $[0,1]$. You will say that $g$ is continuous at $0$ even if it is not defined on the left side of $0$.

Comment: Thank you for helping. This solved my problem!  

Answer (score 0):

When a function is differentiable it is also continuous. So all you need to do is here is prove that $f'(x)$ at $x=0$ exists.

$$f(x) = x (x^{ \frac12 }  - (x+1)^{\frac12})$$
So use product rule:
$$f'(x) = x (\frac12x^{ \frac{-1}2 }  - \frac12(x+1)^{\frac{-1}2}) + (x^{ \frac12 }  - (x+1)^{\frac12})$$
Now sub in $x=0$ and you are left with
$$f'(0) =     -1$$

Thus $f(x)$ is differentiable and therefore continuous at $x=0$

Comment: For the OP, you can know that a function is continuous because of differentiability if you think about the definition of a derivative:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
The only way that this holds is if $f(x)$ is continuous in the region around $x$.

Comment: That argument doesn't work in either direction: Regard $f(x):=|x|$. Then $f'(x)=1$ for $x>0$. So $f'(x)\to1$ for $x\to0$. But it was not differentiable at zero! Comversely, regard $g(x):=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. Then $g'(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{1}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x>0$. So $g'(x)\to'\pm\infty'$ for $x\to0$. But still it was differentiable at zero!

Comment: The absolute value function is a good example of a function that is continuous everywhere, yet differentiable nowhere. However, it is a basic theorem of calculus that differentiability at a point implies continuity at that point. I think you have a differentiation error with g(x) also. I don't think g(x) is differentiable at zero.